# AngularJS and JSON - adding a child object

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, rest

I am using AngularJS and am in my controller.  I have my $scope.tree variable to hold a simple JSON object.  I am trying to build a nested tree and the data is coming from several rest calls.

After my first REST call, I successfully have my initial $scope.tree object:

```
[
     {"name":"Item 1 Name","id":"1","parentid":"","children":[]},
     {"name":"Item 2 Name","id":"2","parentid":"","children":[]}
]
```

I make a second REST call and have 2 elements returned:

```
{"name":"Item 3 Name","id":"3","parentid":"2","children":[]},
{"name":"Item 4 Name","id":"4","parentid":"2","children":[]}
```

and I want to add these as appropriate children to the first call to end up with:

```
[
     {"name":"Item 1 Name","id":"1","children":[]},
     {"name":"Item 2 Name","id":"2","children":[
          {"name":"Item 3 Name","id":"3","parentid":"2","children":[]},
          {"name":"Item 4 Name","id":"4","parentid":"2","children":[]}
     ]}
]
```

A third call:

```
{"name":"Item 5 Name","id":"5","parentid":"3","children":[]},
{"name":"Item 6 Name","id":"6","parentid":"4","children":[]}
```

And end up with:

```
[
     {"name":"Item 1 Name","id":"1","children":[]},
     {"name":"Item 2 Name","id":"2","children":[
          {"name":"Item 3 Name","id":"3","parentid":"2","children":[
              {"name":"Item 5 Name","id":"5","parentid":"3","children":[]}
          ]},
          {"name":"Item 4 Name","id":"4","parentid":"2","children":[
              {"name":"Item 6 Name","id":"6","parentid":"4","children":[]} 
          ]}
     ]}
]
```

In my controller I have something like:

```
$scope.tree = {};
$scope.restcall1 = (results of restcall)
$scope.restcall2 = (results of restcall)
$scope.restcall3 = (results of restcall)

$scope.tree = $scope.restcall1;
```

now I need to join $scope.restcall1 and $scope.restcall2 so I built a treeBuilder service, with an addCall2 method.

```
$scope.tree = treeBuilder.addBranch($scope.tree, $scope.$restcall1);
```

In treeBuilder service:

```
    addBranch: function(branch, tree){
        for (var i=0; i<branch.length; i++){
            network = _.filter(tree, function(obj){
                if(obj.id == branch[i].parentId){
                    obj.children.push(branch[i]);
                }
            });
        }
        return tree;
    },
```

obj.children.push(new_branch); doesnt work, and I have tried 10 other ways - I am finding the parent object just fine but can't find a way to add the branch to the parent.children.  As you see above, I have underscore available to me if that helps.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What i basically understood about what you wanna to do is this:

```
var obj = {
    children:[]
}
obj.children.push({test:'Hello world'});
console.log(obj.children);//[Object { test="Hello world"}]
```

Am i right?

Comment: Exactly, except once I find my parent object I want to push onto, I do:
console.log(obj.children) and get [] (good!)
console.log(new_child) and get {"id:"3", "name":"Object 3"...}
then:
obj.children.push(new_child);
Error: obj.children.push is not a function

Comment: ok, but you've to be sure that all of your objects come with children property, you are doing a loop, some objects can pass correctly and some other not.

Comment: i think that your obj.children is a string and not an array, that's why it doesn't have a push function.

Comment: console.log(typeof obj.children), type it and see.

Comment: I am accepting your answer as correct so you get the points, but technically - the solution was that we had a string - and now I made it an array and push works like it should.  So the answer technically lies in your comments.  Either way a HUUUUUGE thanks!

Comment: ok! good! and one tip, you are receiving your data in json format from your rest call, if you wanna manipulate it in javascript is better you to turn your json to a javascript object.

Answer (score 0):

Your initial tree:

```
[
     {"name":"Item 1 Name","children":[]},
     {"name":"Item 2 Name","children":[]}
]
```

Your second REST call

```
{"name":"Item 3 Name","id":"3","parentid":"2","children":[]},
{"name":"Item 4 Name","id":"4","parentid":"2","children":[]}
```

and your code:

```
addBranch: function(branch, tree){
        for (var i=0; i<branch.length; i++){
            network = _.filter(tree, function(obj){
                if(obj.id == branch[i].parentId){
                    obj.children.push(branch[i]);
                }
            });
        }
        return tree;
    },
```

two things that i noticed, your initial tree doesn't have a "id" or "parent id", how this initial tree would work with your algorithm above?

> your algorithm is "simple", just check if the object(object1) has a
>   "parent id" attribute, if it have, you just hold this object, find in
>   your array of objects(your tree) if an object has (id === parent_id),
>   if true, you just push your object(object1) inside this another object
>   array atribute "children" and after that you just remove your
>   object(object1) from original resource, and look for another object to
>   push in your tree.

Comment: Rodrigo - Sorry I edited my code to make it consistent.  I made a few changes as I went trying to make it clearer. and forgot to edit that call with the ID for the matching later.

Also - my code does the match, so I have both the right spot in the parent and the child but I cant figure out how to push the child onto the parent. obj.children.push(branch[i]) doesnt work - that is what I am looking for

Comment: console.log(branch[i]); Do that and see what is inside the branch.